# How do I prove that $\cosh(x)$ is bijective for the interval $[0,\infty[$?

Tags: trigonometry

I've found out that $\cosh´(x) > 0$ when $x>0$ by graphing. But how do I show that mathematically?

Same thing for when $x$ approaches $\infty$, $\cosh(x)$ approaches $\infty$, but how do I show that?

Do I need to give any additional information?

Comment: That $\cosh(+\infty) = +\infty$ is well-known (or the corresponding limit version if you're limiting yourself to just the ordinary reals) -- if you don't think you're expected to just *use* that fact, then you need to appeal to whatever definition you're given for $\cosh(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x)=\cosh x$, restricted to $[0,\infty)$ is strictly increasing *and* continuous (actually differentiable). Indeed $f'(x)=\sinh x>0$ (for $x>0$).

Since $f(0)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$, the range of $f$ is $[1,\infty)$.